# Unusual syntax for a #define directive

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

In a sketch I found the following instruction:

```
#define USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(mA)                ((mA)/2)
```

And I want to be sure not to make any mistake: why are there two "mA"?

Which one should I replace by a value given that in a previous version of this code one just needed this line:

```
#define USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(20)
```

to set the max to 20mA but now it gives a compilation error:

```
/home/henry/arduino-1.8.16/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/USBCore.h:99:29: error: "20" may not appear in macro parameter list
```

This seems to be the solution as it gives me no compilation error

#define USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(mA)                ((40)/2)

but again i want to be sure!

Comment: I would guess that you never needed to use `#define USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(20)` but only `USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(20)`. The former does not define any replacement text

Answer (score 3):

With

```
#define USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(mA)                ((mA)/2)
```

you define a function-like macro, where `mA` is the *argument* to the macro.

You can use it like:

```
printf("USB power for 20 mA is %d\n", USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(20));
```

The preprocessor will replace the macro as such:

```
printf("USB power for 20 mA is %d\n", ((20)/2));
```

---

If you always want the macro to be replaced by the value `20` then either define a function-like macro where you ignore the argument (this will be backward compatible):

```
#define USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(mA)                20
```

Or define a macro without arguments (this will require you to change all macro invocations):

```
#define USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA                    20
```

The latter, without arguments, is often used in C as a way to define symbolic constants, and as such makes more sense in your use-case.

---

Another possible solution is to use the original macro definition, but use a second macro to define the value to pass as argument:

```
#define USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(mA)                ((mA)/2)
#define USB_CONFIG_DEFAULT_POWER               40

// ...

printf("USB power for 20 mA is %d\n",
       USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(USB_CONFIG_DEFAULT_POWER));
```

This will both be backward compatible and allow other values to be used together with the original `USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA` macro.

Comment: It is not my code. i 'm a simple user with absolutely no experience in C++. just another naive question. Is  #define USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(mA)                20 equivalent to #define USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(mA)                ((40)/2) ? just to be sure

Comment: @FredDarkh Since it's not your code I would recommend that you go with the last suggestion: Don't modify the original macro, and instead create a new macro or other symbolic constant which you pass as "argument" to the original `USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA` macro. That will affect the original code the least.

Answer (score 2):

> to set the max to 20mA

You shouldn't change the definition of the `USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA` macro, you should change the value that's passed to it where it's used. The macro you're talking about comes from [USBCore.h](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/USBCore.h):

```
#define D_CONFIG(_totalLength,_interfaces) \
    { 9, 2, _totalLength,_interfaces, 1, 0, \
      USB_CONFIG_BUS_POWERED | USB_CONFIG_REMOTE_WAKEUP, \
      USB_CONFIG_POWER_MA(USB_CONFIG_POWER) }
```

You can see the macro being used to set the configured power here. Looking deeper, the definition of `USB_CONFIG_POWER` is:

```
#ifndef USB_CONFIG_POWER
  #define USB_CONFIG_POWER      (500)
#endif
```

So `USB_CONFIG_POWER` only gets defined if it isn't already defined. That means that all you need to do to set the power that your Arduino sketch requests is to make sure that you define `USB_CONFIG_POWER` yourself before you include the `USBCore.h` file. Put a line like:

```
#define USB_CONFIG_POWER        (20)
```

in your code before you include that file, and you should be good to go.